# PHP: How to access download folder outside root directory?

Tags: php, apache, download, directory, root

How do I go about creating a PHP script/page that will allow members/buyers to download zipped files(products) stored in a download folder located outside root directory? I'm using Apache server. Please help!

Thanks!
Paul G.

Comment: use full paths or relative paths?

Comment: Check answer on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12094080/download-files-from-server-php

Comment: Probably a bad way to go because you might be running some large files through PHP. You're best of having difficult to guess URLs like Facebook, etc do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're trying to accomplish (stream an existing zip file via php) can be done similar to the answer here:
[LAMP: How to create .Zip of large files for the user on the fly, without disk/CPU thrashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357073/on-the-fly-zipping-streaming-of-large-files-in-php-or-otherwise/4357904#4357904)

---

Slightly modified version of code from this answer:

```
// make sure to send all headers first
// Content-Type is the most important one (probably)
//
header('Content-Type: application/x-gzip');

$filename = "/path/to/zip.zip";
$fp = fopen($filename, "rb");

// pick a bufsize that makes you happy
$bufsize = 8192;
$buff = '';
while( !feof($fp) ) {
   $buff = fread($fp, $bufsize);
   echo $buff;
}
pclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find some better info in the link provided by @soac, but here is an excerpt from some of my code for PDF files only:

```
<?php
      $file = ( !empty($_POST['file']) ? basename(trim($_POST['file'])) : '' );
      $full_path = '/dir1/dir2/dir3/'.$file;  // absolute physical path to file below web root.
      if ( file_exists($full_path) )
      {
         $mimetype = 'application/pdf';

         header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
         header('Cache-Control: no-store');
         header('Pragma: no-cache');
         header('Content-Type: ' . $mimetype);
         header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($full_path));

         $fh = fopen($full_path,"rb");
         while (!feof($fh)) { print(fread($fh, filesize($full_path))); }
         fclose($fh);
      }
      else
      {
         header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
         exit;
      }
?>
```

Note that this opens the PDF in the browser rather than downloading it perse, although you can save the file locally from within the reader. Using `readfile()` would probably be more efficient (and cleaner code) than the old way of opening the file via a handle the way I do in this example.

```
readfile($full_path);
```