# PHP: How to protect digital products(video, audio, ebook, etc.) from unathorized downloading?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, download, digital-downloads

How to protect digital products(video, audio, ebook, etc.) from unauthorized downloading? I'm using Apache server and PHP/MySQL. Please help!

Thanks!
Paul G.

Edited: Sorry for the incomplete question. What I want is to avoid other members from sharing direct download links to the files they have access to non-members. I heard something that it can be done by storing digital products outside the root folder, but I have no idea how to exactly implement it with PHP.

Comment: if available to all ultimately, you cant. Otherwise username\password like any other site

Comment: @Dagon Yes, I know how to that. Sorry for the incomplete question. What I want is to avoid other members from sharing direct download links to the files they have access to non-members. I heard something that it can be done by storing digital products outside the root folder, but I have no idea how to exactly implement it with PHP.

Comment: @netizen0911 update your question, make it more specific. use edit.

Comment: sounds like password\username required for certain site sections then. and or storing outside web root and serving with script - but you need to write a full questions os we can give you a proper answer

Comment: After edit: your previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16471699/php-how-to-access-download-folder-outside-root-directory) on the exact same topic got answers, what was wrong with them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you're trying to protect files that should only be available to "logged-in" users... if you're just trying to stop people from downloading files that are embedded in your site there is really nothing you can do.

So, operating on the premise that you're trying to allow file-access/download only to approved users, your best bet is to only serve protected content through a `php` controller file (let's call it `serve_file.php`). You store the actual files outside the public root directory (or some other inaccessible folder) or you store the files as `BLOB` data in a `MySQL` table.

Then, when a user wants to download a file will be provided with a link to `serve_file.php` with some `_GET` data which identifies the file they're trying to get:

`http://mysite.com/serve_file.php?file_id=24`, for instance.

The `serve_file.php` script takes the `_GET` data, figures out which file it's indicating, and then checks a permissions table (or just checks to see if the user is logged in) and decides whether the user is eligible to receive the file. If they are, it gets the file data (either from MySQL or with `file_get_content()`), spits out appropriate `headers` (depending on what type of file you're serving up) and then `print`/`echo`s the content:

```
//check that the user is logged in (I'm assuming you have a function of this name)
if (!user_logged_in()){
   die('You do not have permission! Please log in');
}

/*see what file the user is trying to get... 
this is a very simple sample that can only get PDFs.
You should probably have a table with file details*/
$file_location = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../protected_files/file_'.intval($_GET['file_id']).'.pdf'
if (!is_file($file_location)){
   die('Could not get that file!');
}

$content = file_get_contents($file_location);
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Length: ".strlen($content));
//add some more headers here, to deal with caching, etc
echo $content;
die();
```

The `header`s you've set tell the user's browser how it should interpret the data you're sending (for instance, as an `Content-Type: application/pdf`) and you've successfully allowed only authorized users from accessing the document because they always have to go through your PHP authentication script.