# Php Mysql and Text Output

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need create an HTML form as CRUD. This form record my inputs as "row_number", "channel_name" and "ip_address". It's record all data to mysql table with "ORDER BY row_number". It's okay, i created and working without edit and delete option.

Then i want add a button and this button export all data to a text file from the table or html list (i mean my records seems on a page as HTML table). But important is it must be export with "row_number" order.

Maybe someone can help me about it. I can use `html+php+javascript`.

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: The question isn't clear because of your english. Did I get it correctly that you want to SELECT data from your database and then print it into an HTML table ordered by the row_number column and at which point are you struggling?

Comment: "Did I get it correctly that you want to SELECT data from your database" = YES

"and then print it into an HTML table ordered by the row_number column and at which point are you struggling?" = No, i want print it into a text file ordered by the row_number column. This point is my problem.

Comment: Could you edit your question to add some example so that we could understand a bit better

Answer (score -1):

these may help you.
I'm not able to comment you'r post because i have low reputation so i had to make "Answer", sorry about that, this may not be the answer but hope it helps you.

Here is basic guide about 
[Create/Write](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_create.asp)
files in php.

Here is stackoverflow tread about how to return files from php to back to browser smartly.
 [return files from php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12094080/download-files-from-server-php)

Hope these will help you out !
Best regards,
Vis25

Comment: Thank you vis25. First link I already looked. Second link is good but not enough for my question. Anyway, Thank you so much.