# PHP list directory and delete or download files

Tags: php, download, directory

I have a directory on my server, I want to list all the files in it with checkboxes and either delete or download them after choosing.

So far I can list and delete fine using this form, ticking checkboxes and pressing the button. But I also sometimes need to download files to my local machine. Either by ticking the checkbox or right-clicking the file name and downloading with 'save file as' in Chrome browser. But I can't get it working.

How can I download these files?

My page is called download-ui.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
    {
    }      
      foreach ($_POST['select'] as $file) {

    if(file_exists($file)) {
        unlink($file); 
    }
    elseif(is_dir($file)) {
        rmdir($file);
    }
}

$files = array();
$dir = opendir('.');
    while(false != ($file = readdir($dir))) {
        if(($file != ".") and ($file != "..") and ($file != "download-ui.php") and ($file != "error_log")) {
                $files[] = $file; 
        }   
    }

    natcasesort($files);
?>

<form id="delete" action="" method="POST">

<?php
echo '<table><tr>'; 
for($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++) { 
    if ($i%5 == 0) { 
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '<tr>'; 
    }       
    echo '<td style="width:180px">
            <div class="select-all-col"><input name="select[]" type="checkbox" class="select" value="'.$files[$i].'"/>
            <a href="download-ui.php?name='.$foldername."/".$files[$i].'" style="cursor: pointer;">'.$files[$i].'</a></div>
            <br />
        </td>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
</table>
<br>
<button type="submit" form="delete" value="Submit">Delete File/s</button>
</form><br>
```

Comment: http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/php-download-file-script/

Comment: @AlivetoDie I need a 100% PHP solution, that link needs a mod installed which I can't do.

Comment: no i don't think that anything need to be installed for that code

Comment: @AlivetoDie I'm not going to argue about it, it says it right there on the link you gave several times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The download-ui.php have to be something like:

```
//Only enter if there is some file to download.
if(isset($_GET['name']){
  $file = basename($_GET['name']); //change if the url is absolute

  if(!$file){ // file does not exist
    die('file not found');
  } else {
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

    // read the file from disk
    readfile($file);
  }
}

//your form
```

This way you are forcing to download the file. If you want it better, you can make a AJAX call when click on 'download' pointing to that url, and the file will be downloaded async, like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'download-ui.php',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function() {
        window.location = 'download-ui.php';
    }
});
```

But without AJAX will work too.

Check this: [Download files from server php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12094080/download-files-from-server-php#12094230)

Hope it helps!

Comment: That form is in download-ui.php, where would I put this code? Under the other?

Comment: If you use the same file for the form & for download the files, you should put a if in the beggining, wrapping all my code. Check my update!
If you use the AJAX, take in consideration changing all the $_GET for $_POST. If you don't want the page to stop if something is wrong, delete the 'die'.

Comment: I can't use AJAX, still lost on how your example will work. How does it know which file to download? If I tick the box of one it will delete it. If I rightclick the filename it tries to save a link called download-ui.htm. Do I need a 'Download' button?

Comment: Without AJAX will work. You have to paste the php code in your first part of the file. The structure will be something like:

- if(submit) { //delete }
- if(get) { //download}
loadFiles
showFiles

You have an error in the code `$foldername` (this var is undefined). You should use `$dir` or something like this. If you click on the link of the name of the file, this should make the download if is all right.

Comment: if I change foldername to dir is still won't download on right click, I think this is where the problem is, it's not giving me a proper link? It just tries to download download-ui.htm

Comment: I'm convinced my href is wrong? any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Which is the URL of the href? Why right click? You have to do a 'normal' click. The url should be like: ./filename.txt, of ./filename.pdf..

Comment: I fixed it, I can now right click and save link as and get my file downloaded by browser... I changed to <a href="'.$files[$i].'" style="cursor: pointer;">'.$files[$i].'</a> thank you very much for the help, you put me on the right track.

Comment: Thats nice, your welcome! Upvote if the response helped ;)