# How can I, using Twig, delete text files listed on a UI page that were generated by frontend forms in a flat-file CMS?

Tags: php, twig, grav

Background for Understanding the Problem I Need to Solve:

1. My new, senior client doesn't deal well with receiving form
   submissions through email, so adding more to his 24,000+ unread
   emails won't work.
2. A database-driven CMS is out of the question for this client as
   well, as is setting him up with a FTP login to read and delete files
   on the server (Yikes, the thought).
3. I don't yet see how I can create IDs for these individual
   form-submitted text files without a db; IDs, of course, would make
   it simple to delete the buggers.

What I've Got Going On So Far:

4. Each form's generated files list with content links on a UI page,
   and each listed file has a fancy but alas non-functioning button I
   made for its respective row.
5. I've tried to delete the files for days by referencing them by
   name using various combinations of the base url and their routes to
   no avail.
6. I've search for and read through similar questions here and
   elsewhere on the Internet, the closest one that still didn't work
   was this [PHP example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44110643/php-list-directory-and-delete-or-download-files) which I will revisit if advised to do so.
7. The flat-file CMS uses data remodals with "uri.addNonce" to
   delete just about everything else in the admin panel, so silly me
   thought this would be easy to emulate.

My Current Non-Working Spanned Button Code:

```
<ul class="pages-list depth-0">
       {% for item in grav.twig.items %}
           <li class="page-item">
               <div class="row page-item__row">
                    <div class="page-item__content">
                        <a href="{{ type }}/{{ item.route }}" class="page-edit item-read">{{ item.route|e }}</a>
                    </div>
                    <span class="page-item__tools">
                        <a href="{{ uri.addNonce(item_url ~ id  ~ '/action' ~ separator ~ 'delete', 'admin-form', 'admin-nonce') }}"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                    </span>
               </div>
           </li>
       {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

No Actual ID Produces This Broken Link:

```
<a href="#delete" class="page-delete delete-action" title="Delete contact-2018-02-23-053425-135837" data-remodal-target="delete" data-delete-url="/admin-panel/plugin-name/actiondelete/admin-nonce:9g641e7102c9cde7eab9924ef05cddd7"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
```

An ID-Based Span As Seen In A Different Plugin Produces This Working Link:

```
<a href="#delete" class="page-delete delete-action" title="Delete 'Record Name'" data-remodal-target="delete" data-delete-url="/admin-panel/plugin-name/entries/id:mz2gc6jwmnfw6ytm/action:delete/admin-nonce:9g641e7102c9cde7eab9924ef05cddd7"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
```

What I Don't Want to Do:

8. Rewriting the entire plugin to make the form submissions append
   to a single JSON entries db seems overkill and would ruin the
   current plugin's optimal data rendering structure.

The Solution If Not a Crazy, Never-Gonna-Work Idea:

9. I'd like to make a button-generated lonely array of one for each
   listed file that would assign it a key/ID, reference its route, and
   finally make the file able to be deleted.

Is my idea even possible? I'll try any Twig/PHP suggestion and do whatever it takes to make this UI data management solution work for my client. So please advise and point me in the right direction. In the end, I'd like to make a good report here, as being able assign on-the-fly IDs to flat files would open up a lot of creative possibilities.