# how do i let user download file from a server

Tags: php, sql-server, database, codeigniter

I am using mssql server and CI in which it auto backups the db file into certain folder now I need to let the user download the file from the server to her local machine.

```
$filename = basename($_GET['file']);
  // Specify file path.
  $path = 'backups/hello.txt';
  $download_file =  $path.$filename;

  if(!empty($filename)){
      // Check file is exists on given path.
      if(file_exists($download_file))
      {
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);  
        readfile($download_file); 
        exit;
      }
      else
      {
        echo 'File does not exists on given path';
      }
   }
}
```

I have tried this one but it says file is unknown.

Comment: I think it should be `$path = 'backups/';`.

Comment: @Spectarion
Message: Undefined index: file

Comment: Show us the link you are visiting.

Comment: @Spectarion
i got that from this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12094080/download-files-from-server-php

Comment: Not that link. You are sending the `file` parameter in the query string using GET method which means that there has to be some link to your download string. Something like `localhost/download.php?file=xxxxx`.

Answer (score 2):

As per php document, can you try like this

**download.php**

```
if (file_exists($file)) {
     header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
     header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');//change your extension of your files
     header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
     header('Expires: 0');
     header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
     header('Pragma: public');
     header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
     readfile($file);
     exit;
  }
```

Comment: $file??????

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: file

Comment: $file is your file location with file  "backups/hello.txt"