# PHP Get files from server

Tags: php, jquery

I am sorry if it sounds like I don’t know what I’m talking about, probably because I don’t (I have never done something like this before).

I am creating a local CMS in PHP, where I want the user to be able to see and download files such as plugins. The plugins will be on a online server, and I therefor want the local CMS to be able to connect, get information and download files from the server. Please help.

Update: I don’t seek out for someone to write the code, I just want some guidelines or links where I can find more information.

Comment: [so] is not a _free coding_ website. Please show us the effort you've put in and what you've tried so far. We're here to help when you run in to problems but **not** to write your code for you. Since it's your first question here I'd recommend you take the [tour] and read the [ask] page to learn how to ask a proper question.

Comment: I think you might find your answer here:
[Download files from server php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12094080/download-files-from-server-php)

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox or whatever file management sites or CMS,show you just a structure of your folder.The files are not actually on the page.To make a scalable application like this requires good understanding of both php and of the server you are planning to run the app from.
But long story short what you display to the user is actually just links to the files.So once you have an API or something that gives you the structure of the folders and files and links to each thing than you just display does.